# Magento : Update price and QTY based on sku price

Tags: php, magento, import, magento-1.7

I have script for the update price and QTY but it takes too much time on live server.I am trying to execute script for 4 to 5 hours but unable complete process. I have also tested script on my localhost it takes around 1 Hour and 30 Min to update 1400 products.

Please check my below script and suggest me idea so i can reduce timing for local and live both.

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('default');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$currentStore = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);

$path = ''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/product_stock_price.csv';
$readfile = file ($path);
$j=0;$k=0;
for ($i=1; $i < count($readfile); $i++ ) {
    $fields = split('"',$readfile[$i]);
    $sku=split(',',$fields[0]);
    $arr=array('sku'=>$sku[0],'stock'=>$fields[1],'price'=>$fields[3]);
    //print_r($arr);
    $sku= $arr['sku'];
    //print_r($sku);die;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

    if ($product) 
    {
        //echo $product->getPrice(); 
        $product->setWebsiteId(1);
        $product->setStoreId(1);
        $product->setPrice($fields[3]);
        $product->save();

        $productId = $product->getId();
        $stockItem =Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
        $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();

        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $fields[1]);

        $stockItem->save();

       // echo $SKU," Updated: Name: '",(string)$XMLproduct->Name,"', Price: ",$fields[3],", Stock level: ",$fields[1];

        $updated++;
        $j+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $k+=1;
        echo $sku." product not found.</br>";
    } 
}

echo "Total Row : ".count($readfile)." Proceed row : ".$i." Inserted Row : ".$j." Not Found : ".$k;


?>
```

Please give me some solution.

Thanks
Jalpesh

Comment: Just set `max_execution_time` to 0 for no limit. Setting it to 18 trillion seconds is a bit silly.

Comment: try magmi, it's super fast

Comment: thanks @Anthony i change `max_execution_time`.

Answer (score 0):

The process is too much heavy since it is running on big catalog.
Instead of using model/collection, you can fire direct sql queries with minimal possible joins as per you need. You can easily create sql or just search for queries like to update qty is at [Magento - update all products inventory with sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107289/magento-update-all-products-inventory-with-sql#answer-6110914)

Comment: Thanks for reply but your given url has not any way to update price.

Comment: That was just one example that you can find your sql queries just by googling. My solution was that you should be using sql queries.